# Lasso Regression - Extracting the penalty term

Tags: lasso

If I run a lasso regression model, and get a series of coefficients, say :

$\widehat{\beta _{1}},\widehat{\beta _{2}},...,\widehat{\beta _{p}}$

Is it legitimate to say that the value of the penalty term (for a given lambda) was:

$\sum \left | \widehat{\beta _{i}} \right |$ ?

In other words, if I manually, "by hand", take the coefficients the computer gave me, and sum them up (with absolute value), will I get the penalty term ? Is it meaningful ? Clearly it can't be calculated without the computer first making the optimization.

Comment: Well you can say lots of things but what meaning do you intend, i.e., what do you actually think this is informative about? It surely means *something* but it may not mean anything that is of use for you.